# Setting the indention of unordered lists

Tags: lists, itemize, indentation

I'd like to set the indention of an itemize-list. How can this be done?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To customize itemize lists and other lists, I recommend to use the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. It provides commands to customize the different dimension of lists as well as their labels, using `key=value` options.

First, load the package:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

Then, for instance, if you like to set both left margin and item indentation to 10pt, for the first level (0):

```
\setitemize[0]{leftmargin=10pt,itemindent=10pt}
```

For example, if the bulletpoints shall align with the left margin of the text, use

```
\setitemize[0]{leftmargin=*}
```

The lengths you may specify:

- horizontal: `leftmargin`, `rightmargin`, `itemindent`, `listparindent`, `labelwidth`, `labelsep`
- vertical: `topsep`, `partopsep`, `parsep`, `itemsep`

You could choose various symbols for the bullets, further you might benefit even more if you also use enumerated lists and wish to modify their appearance.

For complete information, type `texdoc enumitem` at the command prompt or open the [documentation on CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: In the most current version of `enumitem` the command `\setitemize` is deprecated and `\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=10pt,itemindent=10pt]` for setting the first level `itemize` left margin should be preferred.

Answer (score 9):

Define a new environment. Say you wanted a 0.25 inch indentation, something like this could do the trick.

```
\newenvironment{itemize1}{
  \begin{itemize}{$\bullet$}{
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.25in}}}{\end{itemize}}
```

then use the newly defined environment.

```
\begin{itemize1}
\item First item!
\item Second!
\end{itemize1}
```