# Indent/leftmargin of itemize environment without using enumitem

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize

I would like to have a smaller left margin or indent for the `itemize` environment. Currently, I tried so far `\leftmargin` and `\itemindent` but I did not affect the following lines of an entry.

Does anyone know how to setup the `itemize` environment correctly without using `enumitem`?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example to see what exactly you want?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2363/setting-the-indention-of-unordered-lists. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: This is a good question for those trying to customize `itemize` in `beamer` without messing with conflicts between `beamer` and `enumitem` packages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set `\leftmargini` for first level lists as latex sets `\leftmargin` to `\leftmargini` at the start of the list (and `\leftmarginii` for nested lists, etc)