# Environment to change background color of a portion of the page, vertically defined by the height of the contents of the environment?

Tags: mdframed, highlighting, backgrounds

I am trying to highlight some portions of a document. These portions can be paragraphs, images, equations and – quite importantly – list items. The highlighting should preferrably happen by a different background color. I'd like the highlighting to apply to the whole page width (not only the width of the wrapped elements).

Expected output: [image: Expected Output]

I tried to achieve this using `mdframed` but I have the impression it is not the right tool for the job, for two reasons:

- I want to create a box "behind" the text, not a box that *includes* the text: If I use `userdefinedwidth=\paperwidth` on a `mdframed` environment, this also changes the width of the text *in* this environment (illustrated by the image below the code). I only want a wider box around the (otherwise unaffected) text (as shown above).
- `mdframed` can contain lists, but not separate list items.

Is there a package that provides an environment that changes the background color of a portion of the page, vertically defined by the height of the contents of the environment?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

% Problem: Text width changed. 
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,userdefinedwidth=\paperwidth,backgroundcolor=red]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

% Problem: uncommenting breaks document - cannot highlight just one item.
\begin{itemize}
    \item foo
%\begin{mdframed}
    \item bar
%\end{mdframed}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of (not) MWE]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try simulating it with a `tcolorbox` environment instead -- it offers more options for customization instead of `mdframed`. It's especially useful for surrounding the list item with a box/background.

### Update:

The old answer did not take the width of lists into account, sorry about that. I've gone with a slightly different approach here, setting the width of the box directly instead.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newlength{\mymargins}
\setlength{\mymargins}{\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2\relax}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    breakable,
    colback=red!50,
    colframe=red!50,
    width=\paperwidth,
    enlarge left by=-\mymargins,
    left*=0pt,
    right*=\mymargins,
    outer arc=0pt,
    parbox=false,
    #1,
}
\tcbset{list/.style={%
            enlarge left by=-\mymargins-#1,
            after skip=0pt,
            parbox=true,
        }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]

% Multiple paragraphs
\begin{mybox}
    %   \KOMAoptions{parskip=half-}% <-- Restore whatever paragraph settings you have here
    \lipsum[3-4]
\end{mybox}

% Within lists
\begin{itemize}
    \begin{mybox}[list=\leftmargin]
        \item \lipsum[4]
    \end{mybox}
    \item foo
\end{itemize}

% Page breaking
\begin{mybox}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Old solution

Basically the solution is to extend the box to `\paperwidth`, then adjust the internal content back to `\textwidth`.

This works well for general paragraphs (the first scenario in your question), but special care has to be taken for items in lists, by virtue of the way the `\mymargins` (margin length) is calculated in my solution.
In that case, you would need to provide an optional argument `[list=<len>]` to the `\mybox` environment, where `<len>` is the indentation of the list. You should customize this to your own document's settings, but by default (at least in your MWE), the Level-1 lists should work fine.

Page breaking is also supported.

Finally, a note on the `\parskip`, `\parindent` situation in the tcolorbox environments. 
You may need to restore your settings for these lengths within the `tcolorbox` itself, depending on your document's settings.
In particular, since you're using KOMA, I show an example (commented in the code) of how you can do so -- I presume you're using KOMA's parskip etc. settings.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newlength{\mymargins}
\setlength{\mymargins}{\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2\relax}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    breakable,
    colback=red!50,
    colframe=red!50,
    grow to left by=\mymargins,
    left*=0pt,
    grow to right by=\mymargins,
    right*=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    parbox=false,
    #1,
}
\tcbset{list/.style={%
            grow to left by=\mymargins+#1,
            after skip=0pt,
            parbox=true,
        }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3-4]

% Multiple paragraphs
\begin{mybox}
%   \KOMAoptions{parskip=half-}% <-- Restore whatever paragraph settings you have here
    \lipsum[3-4]
\end{mybox}

% Within lists
\begin{itemize}
    \begin{mybox}[list=\leftmargin]
    \item foo
    \end{mybox}
    \item foo
\begin{mybox}[list=\leftmargin]
    \item foo
\end{mybox}
    \item bar
\end{itemize}

% Page breaking
\begin{mybox}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! I almost lost hope to receive such an useful answer.

Comment: @CL. No problem! It was a good question.

Comment: I realized that it seems like the line width is too wide within lists. Do you have a hint for me how to fix this? MWE: Your preamble + `\begin{itemize}
    \begin{mybox}[list=\leftmargin]
    \item \lipsum
    \end{mybox}
\end{itemize}`. Thanks!

Comment: @CL. Hey, sorry about that. See if the changes work well for you.

Comment: Thank you for the update Troy, this works fine! One last follow-up question: If I have a nested list, I need to use `{mybox}[list=2.14\leftmargin]`. Of course, I could just define a nice makro and use this instead of `2.14\leftmargin` but I guess that there must be a cleaner way to get the appropriate indentation.

Comment: Got it. For a nested list I need `list=\dimexpr(\leftmargini+\leftmarginii)` because `leftmargin` is set to `\leftmargini[i...]`, where the number if `i`s reflects the nesting level. [Thanks, David!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79071/37118). In fact, `2.14\leftmarginii` is just `\leftmargini + \leftmarginii`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be TikZ.
The following code is based on an [answer by Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376222/120953) to one of my questions. It requires two runs. It does *not* support pagebreaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {\vphantom{\strutTikzmark}};}

\newcommand{\strutTikzmark}{\strut}

\usepackage{eso-pic}


\newcommand{\highlightColor}{red!70}
\newcommand{\highlightVerMargin}{0pt}

\newcounter{highlightnumber}

\newenvironment{highlight}{%
    \tikzmark{highlight-\thehighlightnumber-start}%
    \ignorespaces
}{%
    \unskip
    \tikzmark{highlight-\thehighlightnumber-end}%
    \edef\tmptikzcontent{%
        \noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \noexpand\fill[\highlightColor] 
                ([yshift=+\highlightVerMargin] current page.west |- highlight-\thehighlightnumber-start.north) rectangle
                ([yshift=-\highlightVerMargin] current page.east |- highlight-\thehighlightnumber-end.south);
        \noexpand\end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
    \expandafter \AddToShipoutPictureBG \expandafter *\expandafter {%
        \tmptikzcontent
    }%
    \stepcounter{highlightnumber}%
}


\begin{document}
    \blindtext

    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\highlightVerMargin}{-3pt}
    \begin{highlight}
        \blindtext
    \end{highlight}
    \endgroup

    \blindtext

    \begin{itemize}
    \item item~a
    \item item~b
    \item
    \begin{highlight}
        item~c
    \item item~d
    \end{highlight}
    \item item~e
    \item item~f
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]