# How I can remove this horizontal space on environments-lists?

Tags: spacing, enumerate, itemize

When I make a list, either with "enumerate" or "itemize" I get the text as follows:
[image]

But I would like to eliminate or reduce the horizontal distance that it occupies:

[image]

[image]

And get something like this:

[image]

An example of the code is

```
 \documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
 \begin{document}
  Some text here
 \begin{enumerate}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
  \end{enumerate}
  Some more text
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps [Setting the indention of unordered lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2363/106162), [Stefan's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2372/106162) applies to both ordered and unordered list.

Comment: the indentation for `enumerate` is usually established by the document class you are using, but there are other methods.  since we don't know what you are doing now, we can't give a reliable answer.  please provide a small. compilable example that demonstrates what how you obtained the result you show at the top of your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

 \begin{document}

  Some text here
 \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
  \end{enumerate}
  Some more text

  \end{document}
```

This results in the left margin of the list being the same as the text left margin. If you want the list leftmargin coincide with the beginning of the item, add the option `leftmargin=*`.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set `leftmargin=*` and specify your `widest` element (if it is more than 9). Below I've also aligned the enumeration to the `left`, but that is not necessary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

Some text here
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,leftmargin=*,widest={10}]
  \item a
  \item b
  \item c
  \setcounter{enumi}{9}
  \item j \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
Some more text

\end{document}
```